# Syncfusion html-pdf Vs JsReoprt html-pdf. Which is better?

Tags: asp.net-core, syncfusion, html-to-pdf, jsreport

I'm trying to create generate dynamic pdf generating from html (will also involve images too, not  just text) in asp.net core and thinking of using either jsReport or Syncfusion for this. which is better? any pros and cons for both? speed? Please what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion HTML to PDF converter supports conversion in .NET Core using WebKit rendering engine. WebKit rendering engine preserves the output PDF document like how the input HTML file/URL is displayed on the WebKit based web browsers (safari). The performance of the converter is purely depends of the input HTML file/URL. The output PDF document preserves all the graphics, images, text, fonts, and the layout of the original HTML document/webpage. So, we suggest you to try our WebKit rendering engine for converting HTML to PDF.

WebKit rendering engine supports more features such as JavaScript, additional delay, bookmarks, forms, toc etc., when converting the HTML to PDF, Please refer below links for more information about HTML to PDF converter.

**UG** : https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/webkit

**FT** :  https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net/html-to-pdf

**Online Sample** : https://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/htmltopdf

**Note**: I work for Syncfusion.